# Apply CSS to the content rendered by {{expression}} in angular js 2

Tags: css, angularjs

`{{expression}}`

Let us assume the output it will give is

> "ABC-DEF,HIJ-KLM"

Now I wanted to have values after and before `"-"` to have different colors.

Since it is coming from an expression I don't know how to proceed.  I tried building pipes for formatting but it did not work.I am not allowed to split JSON
and populate and style the divs separately.

Comment: You need to give us more details about what you have tried.  Please add a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 2):

You can't set css on expression because it is not an html element. If you want to split at '-' and set different color to each part you need to put the parts in two elements (like span or div) and set css on the elements.

Comment: Yeah i guess that is the only way to split the JSON and populate it separately on the front end.